# Grafana dashboard panel showing live signal with 4 hours delay

Tags: plot, grafana, dashboard

I am surprized to see that my grafana plot showing live signal with 4 hour delayed time. I don't know why. Also, I checked the timezone, it is assigned correctly. Presently I am in NY timezone.

Below is the response. Presently my system time is 14:12 PM where as the Grafana dashboard panel shows the live signal with the time is 10:12 AM. What could be wrong here?
[image]

Also, the first few rows obtained as a result of the Grafana query is:
[image]

Comment: What is your data source, what is its configuration? How metrics appear "inside" said data source?

Comment: @markalex I just updated my question. MySql server is my source.

Comment: It seems like your data source contain data not in UTC, but in local time. Grafana expects it in UTC. Look into similar [question](https://community.grafana.com/t/utc-to-local-time-zone-issue-mysql-data-source/42044/4) on community.grafana.com

Comment: @markalex wow! this is new critical knowledge to me. Thanks a ton. But, I am importing MySql data, which has no timestamp in the original place. what should be the solution here? any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: What does "has no timestamp in the original place" means? Result clearly has some kind of timestamp in it. In also might be helpful if you'll share your query.

Comment: @markalex sorry. my bad. typo. It has no timezone information or it is not localized to UTC. MySql query inside the Grafana`SELECT timestamp, Interval, currentMonthsreading, previousMonthspeakreading FROM home_db.daily_values ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10000`

Comment: @markalex I posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76609413/grafana-query-mysql-database-and-compute-30-minute-average

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `markalex` suggestion above,

below is the MySql query:

```
SELECT convert_tz(present_time,'US/Eastern','UTC') as time_stamp, 
Interval, currentMonthsPeakvalue, previousMonthsPeakvalue FROM 
myhome_df.daily_values ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 10000;
```

Present output:

[image]